# Setting silent mode at a specific area by bluetooth on android

Tags: android

I want to developing an application which can but the mobile auto silent at a specific area, for example: i will but a bluetooth device in my company meeting room and that device name with: "a", i want my App. to set the mobile into silent mode when I enter to that meeting room, can I do that? how? can you please tell me how or tell me the keys of do that? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this would be possible. Your best bet is to start at the [Bluetooth interfaces](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) page in the Android API documents. You'd probably want to have a service that would poll at some interval for available Bluetooth devices searching for the one you're looking for. If you find the device, use the AudioManager to set the ringer mode.

The biggest problem is the effect on battery life. A Bluetooth discovery takes anywhere up to 12 seconds to perform. If you do that every minute your battery will be dead in no time. So you'll have to determine if that's something your users will want.

Comment: Thank you, this is part of App. and i do not know another way to put mobile at silent mode Automatically in specific area inside building (you know gps not working there), there is another way you know?
about battery i think all i can do is to set it to discover in specific hours ,let say from 8-11:30 am Which is work time